# VS 2022 Solution Explorer Auto collapse of expanded items

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know why VS 2022's Solution Explorer automatically collapses items that are expanded (well after the initial project load)?  I like to expand models so I can see all of the members/properties in the Solution Explorer while I am writing code to fill it.  But for some reason VS 2022 Solution Explorer collapses the expanded model after an unknown time interval or event.  VS 2019 did not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was an ongoing bug with Visual Studio.  It appears to have been patched in the [17.5 release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.5.0).

> - [Solution Explorer item collapses by itself](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Solution-Explorer-item-collapses-by-itse/10058437)

Previous link shows that a fix was released in February 2023.  Testing it myself (using Visual Studio 2022 Preview version 17.6), solution explorer no longer collapses.